# Drools Fusion time based sliding window AND attribute filtre

Tags: drools, complex-event-processing, drools-fusion

I try to use a sliding time window in Drools 5.4.0.Final and given the following official documentation snippets:

```
StockTick() over window:time( 2m )
```

and

```
StockTick( company == "RHT" ) over window:length( 10 )
```

I was thinking that the mixed form was valid:

```
StockTick( company == "RHT" ) over window:time( 2m )
```

But, unless I'm mistaken, it doesn't behaves as expected (i.e consider only the RHT Stock Ticks that happened in the last 2 minutes). And I didn't understand the logic of the result.

Somebody could explain me the trick please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Drools versions cause two different behaviors (same Unit Test). So I think my misunderstood comes from a bug in "windows" behavior. I can't be more specific this time.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `drools-fusion-docs` chapter `2.6.1. Sliding Time Windows` there is an aggregating example. Here is a variation that should fit your need.

```
rule "At least one RHT in the last 2 minutes"
when
    Number( intValue > 0 ) from accumulate(
        $tick = StockTick( company == "RHT" ) over window:time( 2m ),
        count( $tick ) )
then
    // do something here
end
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I forget to close my 2 Drools questions actually. I have some weird behavior with Drools Fusion. I'm pretty sure it was a bugged version but I can't say that since I can't be more specific (question time was a rushed time for me - my bad). The only certain thing is : with different versions of Drools, I have different TU behaviors. :(

Anyway thanks for your time !